# Como usar Auth::user()->id na route?

Tags: php, laravel

```
| id | user_id | url_to | controller |  isAuthorized |
| 1  |    1    |  page1 | DadosCtrl  |       1       |  
| 2  |    2    |  page3 | Dados3Ctrl |       1       |  
| 3  |    1    |  page2 | Dados2Ctrl |       1       |
```

Tenho um middleware que só é permitido a entrada de quem é autorizado (`isAuthorized = 1`).
Porém tenho que fazer uma permissão para que um `user` não tenha acesso ao `Controller` do outro

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'pages.auth']], function(){

    echo Auth::user()->id; // ERRO : Trying to get property of non-object
    Route::get('pages', 'Pages\PagesController@index');
    $pages = Pages::where('isAuthorized', true)->get();
    //$pages = Pages::where('isAuthorized', true)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get(); 
    // precisaria do Auth::user()->id, mas ocorre um erro
    foreach($pages AS $p){
        $s = $p->page;
        Route::get($s->url_to.'/', "Pages\\$s->controller@index");
        Route::get($s->url_to.'/{id}', "Pages\\$s->controller@show");
    }
});
```

O usuário só poderá ter acesso ao `Controller` referente ao dele e se estiver autorizado. Não poderá ter acesso ao `Controller` de outro `user`.
por exemplo:

- Se `user_id => 1`:  poderá ter acesso ao `Controller` `DadosCtrl` e `Dados2Ctrl`; se ele acessar o `Dados3Ctrl`, ele não terá acesso.
- Se `user_id => 2`:  poderá ter acesso ao `Controller` `Dados3Ctrl`; se ele acessar o `DadosCtrl` e  `Dados2Ctrl`, ele não terá acesso.

Está retornando um erro `Trying to get property of non-object` ao usar `Auth::user->id` na rota.

Answer (score 0):

Você instancia o facade para o **Auth::** ?

> usando o facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

> // recebe o usuario atual
>   :

```
 $user = Auth::user();
```

> // recebe o id do usuário atual:

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

[Referência  - autenticação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)

--

Sugiro usar um **Middleware** para "filtar" o usuário a uma respectiva rota.

[referência - laravel middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

*Não escrevi o código porque estou um pouco enferrujado no laravel;

Comment: Auth::id() está retornando ``null``

Comment: Estranho, você esta usando o `$user = Auth::user();` para receber o usuário atual ?